# data did not store the data in the same row in a database

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with updating the data in the database. I'm trying to update the data in each row in the same row as the program title.

When I try this:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE programs(channel TEXT, title TEXT, start_date TIMESTAMP, stop_date TIMESTAMP, button_id TEXT, description TEXT)')
con.commit()


for program in channel.findall('programme'):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO programs(channel, title, start_date, stop_date)" + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", [channel_name, title, start_time, stop_time])

programs_id = list()

for elem in program_button:
    programs_id.append(elem.getId())
programs_id = map(str, programs_id)

#store the id of buttons in a database
for ids, title in zip(programs_id, prog_title):
    cur.execute("UPDATE programs SET button_id = ? WHERE title=?", ([ids, title]))
con.commit()
cur.close()
```

It will update the data that are not in the same row as the program title

```
#yields:    
#channel      | title            | start_date  | stop_date  | button_id | description
###########################################################################
#BBC One     | Tomorrow's Food   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3003      | blank
#BBC One     | BBC News at Ten   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3056      | blank
#BBC One     | South E Today     | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3125      | blank
#BBC One     | A Question of S   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3006      | blank
#BBC One     | Film 2016         | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3007      | blank
```

It should be like this:

```
#yields:    
#channel      | title            | start_date  | stop_date  | button_id | description
###########################################################################
#BBC One     | Tomorrow's Food   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3003      | blank
#BBC One     | BBC News at Ten   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3004      | blank
#BBC One     | South E Today     | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3005      | blank
#BBC One     | A Question of S   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3006      | blank
#BBC One     | Film 2016         | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3007      | blank
```

I am using the variables `channel_name`, `title`, `start_time` and `stop_time` to store the information in a database so i could use to get the data from start_time and stop_time to calculating the times. I can't be able to use the `button_id` in the insert line when i have not add the list of objects otherwise it will return as empty.

Here is the list of ids when i use print ids under the loop in the update lines:

```
3003
3004
3005
3006
3007
3008
3009
3010
3011
3012
```

Here is the list of title when i use `print title` under the loop in the update lines:

```
Tomorrow's Food
BBC News at Ten
South East Today
A Question of Sport
Film 2016
The Lookout
Weather for the Week Ahead
BBC News
Breakfast
Food: Truth or Scare
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
>>> find Tomorrow's Food in the title then store 3003 in the same row
>>> find BBC News at Ten in the title then store 3004 in the same row
>>> find South East Today in the title then store 3005 in the same row
>>> find A Question of Sport in the title then store 3006 in the same row
>>> find Film 2016 in the title then store 3007 in the same row
>>> find The Lookout in the title then store 3008 in the same row
>>> find Weather for the Week Ahead in the title then store 3009 in the same row
>>> find BBC News in the title then store 3010 in the same row
>>> find Breakfast in the title then store 3011 in the same row
>>> find Food: Truth or Scare in the title then store 3012 in the same row
```

So how I can update the `button_id` in the update lines to allow me to put the data in the right place the same row as the title?

**EDIT: Here is the list of full data in a database:**

```
#yields:    
#channel      | title            | start_date  | stop_date  | button_id | description
###########################################################################
#BBC One     | Tomorrow's Food   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3003      | blank
#BBC One     | BBC News at Ten   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3056      | blank
#BBC One     | South E Today     | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3125      | blank
#BBC One     | A Question of S   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3006      | blank
#BBC One     | Film 2016         | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3007      | blank
#BBC One     | The Lookout       | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3008       | blank
#BBC One     | Weather for the   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3108       | blank
#BBC One     | BBC News          | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3240       | blank
#BBC One     | Breakfast         | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3110       | blank
#BBC One     | Food: Truth or    | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3234       | blank
#BBC One     | Homes Under the   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3192       | blank
#BBC One     | Wanted Down Under | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3235       | blank
#BBC One     | Claimed and S     | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3236       | blank
#BBC One     | Bargain Hunt      | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3248       | blank
#BBC One     | BBC News at One   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3116       | blank
#BBC One     | South East Today  | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3125       | blank
#BBC One     | Doctors           | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3118       | blank
#BBC One     | Moving On         | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3119       | blank
#BBC One     | Escape to the C   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3120       | blank
#BBC One     | Holiday of My Lif | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3121       | blank
#BBC One     | Flog It!          | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3224       | blank
#BBC One     | Pointless         | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3123       | blank
#BBC One     | BBC News at Six   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3124       | blank
#BBC One     | South East Today  | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3125       | blank
#BBC One     | The One Show      | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3126       | blank
#BBC One     | EastEnders        | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3128       | blank
#BBC One     | Room 101          | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3029       | blank
#BBC One     | EastEnders        | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3128       | blank
#BBC One     | Death in Paradise | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3031       | blank
```

Here is the full title:

```
Tomorrow's Food
BBC News at Ten
South E Today
A Question of S
Film 2016
The Lookout
Weather for the
BBC News
Breakfast
Food: Truth or
Homes Under the
Wanted Down Under
Claimed and S
Bargain Hunt
BBC News at One
South East Today
Doctors
Moving On
Escape to the C
Holiday of My Life
Flog It!
Pointless
BBC News at Six
South East Today
The One Show
EastEnders
Room 101
EastEnders
Death in Paradise
```

Comment: `program_width` is a list of strings that i created the width to store in a different database table.

Comment: In 2016, you'd better use Python 3 than Python 2.7 :p

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary oops sorry i just saw it and i didn't realised it. I have changed the code in my question. Please see my question that I have updated.

Comment: @JulienPalard do you know how i can update the data in each row the same row as the title?

Comment: @Rob in Python 3, yes.

Comment: if you can post the code then that would be great. :P

Comment: @Rob Updated version looks good to me. What's your current output?

Comment: huh? what you mean my current output?

Comment: @Rob What's the state of DB after running the above code?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean? please be clarify?

Comment: Is the list of title's you posted the full list or just a subset? There may be duplicate titles that overwrite the button_ids later on in your loop.

Comment: it just a short way to show you as example, but i have updated the title and database in my question, please check it and let me know if you can help me to set the button ids in the number order that start from 3003, 3004, 3005, 3006...etc to whatever it is.

Comment: @Craig i am still waiting for your answer.....Please stop ignoring me...

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. In your full dataset some of the titles are repeated, every time your SQL statement runs it updates *all* the rows with that title. For example that's why all the 'South East Today' rows have the same button_id

Comment: Thats okay, so do you know what i would need to do? do I have to use the update line under the `for channel in channels` loop to allowed me to store the button_id in a database like 7 times?

Comment: I don't see the 'for channel in channels' loop that you're talking about in the code pasted above, unless you're talking about the loop that calls UPDATE? Also, when you create the **programs** table do you have access to a field that is unique? That way you can use that instead of title to be sure that you only update one row at a time